Can we determine into how many regions the zero set of a polynomial divides the plane?
Disclaimer: If you look at my other questions, you will see that I am still learning the basics of algebra. I am well aware that the answer to this question is likely to go beyond my current level of knowledge. This is fine however, as I am mainly asking this question to get some references as to which areas of algebra(ic geometry) I should study to understand questions like this, so that one day I can come back to it and understand fully what is going on.
Consider a polynomial $p\in\Bbb R[X,Y]$. If it has no roots, the roots are isolated points, or we are dealing with the zero polynomial the answer is trivial. We are therefore only interested in the case where $Z(p)$ is a one-dimensional subset of $\Bbb R^2$. A simple example to consider is then:
$$
aX^2 + bY^2 - c = 0
$$
where, even if we did not know that the zero set was an ellipse, we could reasonably guess that the curve is closed since both $X$ and $Y$ are bounded. This immediately implies that the curve divides the plane into two regions, one bounded and one unbounded. Another example is a hyperbola
$$
aX^2 - bY^2 - c = 0
$$
where now $X$ and $Y$ are unbounded, the zero set consists of two disjoint one-dimensional sets and therefore it divides the plane into three unbounded areas. A more interesting case is the Tschirnhaus cubic:
$$
X^3 - X^2 + Y^2 = 0
$$
which is a connected curve with a singularity, from which we can deduce that it divides the plane into three segments; One bounded and two unbounded. Now these are nontrivial conclusions, and require some work to arrive at and rigorously justify. Now I ask: Is there a single (algorithmic) way to determine into how many segments any given polynomial
$$
\sum a_{ij}X^iY^j\quad a_{ij}\in \Bbb R
$$
will divide the plane, and which of them are bounded/unbounded? And if there is, can it be generalized to arbitrary many variables? And if it does not work over $\Bbb R$, would it at least work over an algebraically closed field?

Just an observation: the constant term will play a role

Indeed, as will all coefficients - a quartic formed by multiplying two circle equations will divide the plane into 3 or 4 regions, depending on if the circles intersect in two points or less than two points.

Have you thought of algorithmically analysing (maybe the extremas) the contour plot? Won’t do any good on polynomials like your last example though, most probably…

Nothing more than an idea: suppose you have $P(x,y)$. Now $P$ can have maxima, minima and saddle points. Suppose we are checking for the case $P(x,y)-c=0$. This is the same as thinking of the intersection of $z=P(x,y)$ and $z=c$. Now think of changing $c$, thus sliding the plane of intersection. Let $N$ denote the number of regions in which $\mathbb{R}^2$ is divided by $P(x,y)-c=0$. Whenever we move the plane of intersection through a minima, maxima or saddle point of $P$, $N$ will change; but it never changes in between. See this graph

I think perhaps cylindrical algebraic decomposition is the algorithm you need.

I don't believe that anything close to a full answer is known.  This is relevant:  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/68954/maximal-number-of-connected-components-of-complement-to-an-affine-plane-real-alg
